# Vertical alignment in tabular not working.. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am clueless. Can anyone tell me why latex is NOT vertically centering my table?
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{2cm}|>{\centering}m{2cm}|>{\centering}m{2cm}|>{\centering}m{2cm}|}
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|}{} & Answer 1 & Answer 2 & Answer 3\tabularnewline[5pt]
\hline 
$\sin\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{AC}$ & $\dfrac{AC}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{BC}{AC}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
$\cos\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AC}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{AC}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
$\tan\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{CB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{AC}{AB}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

This is what I get with this MWE. It's worse in my actual file (no central alignment at all).
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get your output with a current latex.

Comment: Can we see the log from your compilation of this exact code example?

Comment: I still see a wrong space after C in CAB... Am I the only one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook (example 4.8)

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\center
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Answer 1 & Answer 2 & Answer 3\tabularnewline[5pt]
\hline 
$\sin\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{AC}$ & $\dfrac{AC}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{BC}{AC}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
$\cos\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AC}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{AC}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
$\tan\widehat{CAB}$ & $\dfrac{AB}{CB}$ & $\dfrac{CB}{AB}$ & $\dfrac{AC}{AB}$\tabularnewline[10pt]
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using the new `tabularray` package ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)). The package allows you to completely separate format and content.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
% horizontally and vertically centered column with specified width
\NewColumnType{C}[1]{Q[c,m,wd=#1]}

% tblr environment allows complete separation of format and content
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec=*{4}{C{2cm}},
        hline{1}={2-Z}{solid}, hline{2-Z},
        vline{1}={2-Z}{solid}, vline{2-Z},
        cell{2-Z}{1-Z}={mode=math},
        row{2-Z}={rowsep=4pt},
    }
    & Answer 1 & Answer 2 & Answer 3 \\
    \sin\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{AB}{AC} & \dfrac{AC}{AB} & \dfrac{BC}{AC} \\
    \cos\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{CB}{AB} & \dfrac{CB}{AC} & \dfrac{AB}{AC} \\
    \tan\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{AB}{CB} & \dfrac{CB}{AB} & \dfrac{AC}{AB} \\
\end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output table]

The package has better vertical spacing by default. Additionally, I set `rowsep` to `4pt` (default=`2pt`) for rows 2-4 to improve readability.

EDIT: Inspired by Mico's answer, here is another solution with `tabullarray` and `booktabs`. In my opinion, this formatting is much better than with vertical lines. Make sure to add `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}` to use it.

```
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec=*{4}{c},
        cell{2-Z}{1-Z}={mode=math},
        row{2-Z}={rowsep=4pt},
    }
    \toprule
    & Answer 1 & Answer 2 & Answer 3 \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    \sin\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{AB}{AC} & \dfrac{AC}{AB} & \dfrac{BC}{AC} \\
    \cos\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{CB}{AB} & \dfrac{CB}{AC} & \dfrac{AB}{AC} \\
    \tan\widehat{CAB} & \dfrac{AB}{CB} & \dfrac{CB}{AB} & \dfrac{AC}{AB} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
```

[image: output booktabs]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. At first, I had a `tabularray.sty not found` error but when I complied with LaTeX 2021 (Latex3? not used to it so far) I had another list of errors.. And the result is still not vertically centered, with a fist line of "Z"s ..

Comment: The package is fairly new, so you need a recent tex-distribution. For current `miktex` and `texlive` the example should compile properly. As a workaround, you could place the `tabularray.sty` file in your main project folder.

Answer (score 4):

Since automatic line-breaking within cells doesn't seem to be needed for the table at hand, employing `p` (or `m`) column types seems like overkill. If you must have fixed-width and centered columns, I suggest you employ the `wc` column type that's provided by the `array` package.

I would also switch from a `tabular` to an `array` environment, since all cells are math-y. To increase the distance between the fraction terms and the horizontal lines, I suggest inserting some `\mathstrut` directives. The result of making these changes is shown in the first table below.

It's not clear to me, though, why the cells have to be 2cm wide. The result of employing `c` instead of `wc` columns is shown in the middle table below.

If you can get yourself to get rid of all vertical lines and the majority of horizontal lines and employ the macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining few horizontal lines, you can also dispense with the `\mathstrut` directives; see the third table below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % for 'wc' column type
\newcommand\wCAB{\widehat{\mathit{CAB}}}
\let\ms\mathstrut

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
$\begin{array}{| *{4}{>{\displaystyle}wc{2cm}|} }
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textup{Answer 1} & \textup{Answer 2} & \textup{Answer 3} \\
\hline 
\sin\wCAB & \frac{AB^{\ms}}{AC\ms} & \frac{AC}{AB} & \frac{BC}{AC}\\
\hline 
\cos\wCAB & \frac{CB^{\ms}}{AB\ms} & \frac{CB}{AC} & \frac{AB}{AC}\\
\hline 
\tan\wCAB & \frac{AB^{\ms}}{CB\ms} & \frac{CB}{AB} & \frac{AC}{AB}\\
\hline 
\end{array}$

\bigskip
$\begin{array}{| *{4}{>{\displaystyle}c|} }
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textup{Answer 1} & \textup{Answer 2} & \textup{Answer 3} \\
\hline 
\sin\wCAB & \frac{AB^{\ms}}{AC\ms} & \frac{AC}{AB} & \frac{BC}{AC}\\
\hline 
\cos\wCAB & \frac{CB^{\ms}}{AB\ms} & \frac{CB}{AC} & \frac{AB}{AC}\\
\hline 
\tan\wCAB & \frac{AB^{\ms}}{CB\ms} & \frac{CB}{AB} & \frac{AC}{AB}\\
\hline 
\end{array}$

\bigskip\setlength
\extrarowheight{0pt} % reset '\extrarowheihgt` parmeter
$\begin{array}{@{} *{4}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule 
 & \textup{Answer 1} & \textup{Answer 2} & \textup{Answer 3} \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){2-4}
\sin\wCAB & \frac{AB}{AC} & \frac{AC}{AB} & \frac{BC}{AC}\\
\addlinespace[2ex]
\cos\wCAB & \frac{CB}{AB} & \frac{CB}{AC} & \frac{AB}{AC}\\
\addlinespace[2ex]
\tan\wCAB & \frac{AB}{CB} & \frac{CB}{AB} & \frac{AC}{AB}\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent job. I am without Internet on  my notebook and i am stop with my score since three weeks

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's showing me this error: `Illegal pream-token (w): 'c' used`

Comment: @stargazer45 - Do you load the `array` package? Assuming you have a TeX distribution that's been updated in the past two years, that package provides the definition of the `w` column type.